# JAVA: How do I accept arguments sent to a method as a comma separated characters in square brackets?

Tags: java, list, constructor

I have the following class in which I need to edit the constructor function:

```
public final class ZNumber {
private final String Znum;
public ZNumber(){
```

}

```
ZNumber zn = new ZNumber(['A','B','C','D']);
```

This is how my constructor needs to be initialized. The constructor is supposed to set the value of Znum as "ABCD". Number of arguments could be variable and could be any of the alphabets.

I'm new to programming, kindly tell me how do I accept the arguments passed in square brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can used a char[] :

```
ZNumber zn = new ZNumber(new char[] {'A','B','C','D'});

public ZNumber(char[] arr){
    this.Znum = new String(arr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use varargs and your call might look better:

```
public final class ZNumber {
    private final String Znum;
    public ZNumber(char... numbers){
      Znum = new String(numbers);
    }
}
```

You can call this as follows:

```
new ZNumber('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your constructor to:

```
public ZNumber(char[] charArray){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class ZNumber {
    private String Znum="";

    public ZNumber(char[] arr){
        for (char elem : arr) {
            Znum+=elem;
        }
    }

}
```

This is how to instantiate your class:

```
char[] ar = {'A','B','C','D'};
ZNumber zn = new ZNumber(ar);
```

The variable `Znum` of the class `Znumber` will contain *ABCD*

Answer (score 0):

Here is my two cents. I added two constructors. One with a char[] parameter and the other one with a String. The former calls the latter.

public class ZNumber{
       private String data;

```
   public ZNumber(String in){
     data = in;
   }

   public ZNumber(char[] in){
      this(String.valueOf(in);
   }

}
```